# When we run maprreduce with Apache ignite, does the mapper output still written to local filesystem i.e. mapper output will not be in-memory

Tags: ignite

When we run maprreduce with ignite, does the mapper output still written to local filesystem i.e. mapper output will not be in-memory. Thus I/O operation on the local filesystem at mapper side still exists?

Comment: Are you running Hadoop map-reduce or Ignite's native Compute Grid?

Comment: I'm running map-reduce using Apache Ignite's Hadoop Accelerator using IGFS.

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop will work with the filesystem that is specified in its configuration files. If this file system is IGFS, than everything will be written there.

---

**UPDATE** (copy-paste from corresponding user thread http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/MapReduce-with-Apache-Ignite-td8007.html).

Currently mapper output is stored in-memory only. We are working on spilling algorithm at the moment which will flush part of it to the disk according to some pre-configured thresholds. 
As per job logs, they are not supported at the moment by Ignite in the same way as it is done for Hadoop. We add similar functionality soon.

Comment: Though Hadoop says use HDFS, the mapper output is written to local filesystem and not HDFS, so this exception applies to Hadoop over apache ignite?

Comment: Please help me with the follow-up questions.

Comment: Updated the response

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I've a follow up question to it. The mapper output is written to memory & spilling is being worked on. So in the current version when mapper output is bigger than java heap, the data is evicted thus we may loose data? or node will crash complaining out of memory error